# How to retrieve the file name of an image in Parse.com, for an Android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parse-platform

I am storing small images inside a table. The field called "questionImage" is storing these images.

The table looks as follows:

[image: table]

I have two questions:

1. How can I retrieve the file name of the image files? For example, the first object in the table above has an image named "5D_C.png". How can I get that name using Java in Aandroid? I am using Eclipse, if that makes any difference.
2. Is there a way to import these images in a batch? For example, if I didn't have any image fields, I could have made an Excel sheet of my data and exported it as CSV into Parse.com. Is the same workflow achievable with image fields inside a class?

Comment: you asked this question before, you need go to Parse forum to find your problem , this is not a good place for asking this question

Comment: Retrieving file name requires coding doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make a **Parse query** to obtain for the objects you are interested in. See [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries)
Then,  in the callback, you can iterate over these elements to collect the file names. Something like this:

```
public void done(List<ParseObject> objsList, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + objsList.size() + " things");

        ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ParseObject ob : objsList) {
            //This is the important part
            String fileName = ob.getParseFile("questionImage").getName();
            fileNames.add(fileName);
        }

    } else {
        Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Similarily, if you want to obtain the files, you can (in the same interation), get the file and save it

```
 byte[] bitmapdata = ob.getParseFile("questionImage").getData();
 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata, 0, bitmapdata.length);
 //Save bitmap in a file
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**: not sure if I understood correctly your question. With "import" you mean **get** the images from parse or **upload** them to parse. Parse is not designed to make massive operations (batch operations are quite limited).